# Set background of preference according to the position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-10.0

I am developing an app where I am using `Preference` (`androidx.preference.Preference`).
I am using `PreferenceCategory` and adding `Preerence` to it at runtime.

My requirement is that the first, middle and last preferences in `PreferenceCategory` should have different backgrounds and layouts. I am using following code for this :

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    Activity activity = null;
    String TAG = "SettingsFragment";
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = (Activity) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        PreferenceCategory category = findPreference("MyPreference");
        category.setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_group_layout);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(category);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            Preference preference = new Preference(activity);
            preference.setKey("P" + i);
            preference.setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_layout);
            category.addPreference(preference);
            Log.d(TAG,"" + category.getPreferenceCount());
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}

class MyAdapter extends PreferenceGroupAdapter {
    String TAG = "MyAdapter";
    public MyAdapter(PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup) {
        super(preferenceGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Preference getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PreferenceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreateViewHolder called");
        return super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PreferenceViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder called");
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    }
}
```

But This is not showing my `Prefrence` in layout. I searched on internet about this but I didn't find any similar example. How can I add `Preference` and set their layout according to their positions.

Comment: did you face any issue to implement the suggested solution? as you neither responded nor allocated the  bounty?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the color in `onBindViewHolder':

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PreferenceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder called");
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        case 1:
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            .....
            .....
        default: 
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Control is not reaching this function

Comment: looks like adapter is not binding with preference category.

Comment: for that you've to **override** `onCreateAdapter(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen)` method

Comment: This method is in PreferenceFragment class but I have multiple preferencegroups in my fragment.

Comment: What I want is to format layouts of different preferences in many preference categories.

Answer (score 1):

`PreferenceGroupAdapter` object has the `preference` data but adapter is not linked with the fragment means, `adapter` is not being used so do this via overriding `onCreateAdapter` in your `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and return your adapter object as:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    Activity activity = null;
    String TAG = "SettingsFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    // Add this with modified logic
    @Override
    protected RecyclerView.Adapter onCreateAdapter(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
        PreferenceCategory category = findPreference("MyPreference");
        category.setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_group_layout);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(category);
        final int tot = 10;
        final int middle = tot / 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= tot; i++) {
            Preference preference = new Preference(activity);
            preference.setKey("P" + i);
            int layout = R.layout.preference_layout;
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    layout = R.layout.preference_layout_first;
                    break;
                case middle:
                    layout = R.layout.preference_layout_middle;
                    break;
                case tot: // last
                    layout = R.layout.preference_layout_last;
                    break;
            }
            preference.setLayoutResource(layout);
            category.addPreference(preference);
            Log.d(TAG, "" + category.getPreferenceCount());
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return myAdapter;
    }
}
```

[image]